# ActiveRecord - where query based on has_one association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

My application has two classes:

```
class Class1 < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :class2
end

class Class2 < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :class1
end
```

What is the best way to construct the query that selects all instances of class1 which have Class2?  It is kinda easy on class2, but is there an easy way to do it on class1?

```
Class1.where("class2 is present")
```

Comment: Did you mean "all instances of class1 which have Class2"?

Comment: yep that's right! I've fixed the typo.

Comment: Doesn't `Class1.joins(:class2)` give you what you need?

Comment: Yep, that what I was after!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think an `inner join` will give you what you are looking for.  Something like following:

```
Class1.joins(:class2)
```